# CoreData stack with persistence container inside framework

Tags: ios, core-data

I try to build a framework with CoreData inside. I init CoreData stack with container from iOS 10 file is looks like this

```
class CoreDataStack {

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MySDK")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext() {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

func insert(check: Check) {
    guard let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CheckEntity", in: persistentContainer.viewContext) else { return }

    let managedObject = CheckEntity(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: persistentContainer.viewContext)

    managedObject.total = Int64(check.total)


    if let payment = check.payment {
        guard let paymentEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "PaymentEntity", in: persistentContainer.viewContext) else { return }
        let paymentEntityObject = PaymentEntity(entity: paymentEntity, insertInto: persistentContainer.viewContext)

        paymentEntityObject.amount = Int64(payment.amount)
        managedObject.addToPayment(paymentEntityObject)
    }

    for item in check.items {
        guard let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CheckItemEntity", in: persistentContainer.viewContext) else { return }
        let printerCheckItemEntity = CheckItemEntity(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: persistentContainer.viewContext)


        printerCheckItemEntity.uuid = item.uuid
        managedObject.addToItems(printerCheckItemEntity)
    }

    saveContext()
}
```

}

the problem is that when I try to call method `insert` get crash

> 2019-01-14 18:30:04.115533+0300 MySDKTest[20465:33363837] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a
>   legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name
>   'CheckEntity''

What am I doing wrong ?